# Sharing My USB Storage on remote desktop server

Tags: windows, networking, storage, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a server with public IP number running windows server 2019 .
I can access this server via remote desktop through my personal computer.
Is it possible to share my USB storage from my personal computer and make it appear on  public server.

The purpose behind that is to increase storage capacity to take backup of files on it.

Please write steps how do to that if it's doable.

Comment: you can if enabled wccess it mostly, but bot permanently

Comment: You can configure Microsoft RDP client to make local drives available in an RDP session. Those may then be used for making backups as long as the backup tool runs in your use account.

Comment: can you write steps of doing it  @Robert

Comment: Just enable in "local resources" the drives in the Microsoft RDP client which is included in Windows (`mstsc.exe`).

Comment: ok if did that would the usb in my pc appear there ?